# Proof verification/check for Iterations of interior and closure on a set in Topological Space.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove that in any Topological Space $(\mathbb{X}, \tau)$ and any $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$ we have that $$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A).$$

(My) Proof: Let $(\Bbb{X}, \tau)$ be a Topological Space and $A \subseteq \Bbb{X}$. We can then write $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \implies \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \implies \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A)$, i.e. we have that the following inclusion holds
$$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A). \quad (1)$$

On the other hand, $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A) \implies 
\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A)  \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A) \implies \operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A)$, looking at the end inclusion we see $\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A)$. By monotonicity of interior we have that the following inclusion holds
$$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A). \quad (2)$$
By (1) and (2) we have the following equality holds $$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A),$$ as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to start with $\operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A = \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A$ but just note that $B \subseteq \operatorname{cl} B$ holds for all $B$ so also for $B = \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A $ so that

$$\operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A \subseteq \operatorname{cl} \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A\tag{1}$$

and then we take $\operatorname{int}$ on both sides by monotonicity of the interior and we get

$$\operatorname{int}  \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A = \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A \subseteq \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A\tag{2}$$

and we're done for one half.

For the other half note that $\operatorname{int}(B) \subseteq B$ for all $B$, and apply it to $B= \operatorname{cl} A$ to get

$$ \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A \subseteq \operatorname{cl}  A$$ and taking the closure on both sides:

$$\operatorname{cl} \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A \subseteq \operatorname{cl} \operatorname{cl}  A = \operatorname{cl} A\tag{3}$$

and taking the interior on both sides of $(3)$ we get

$$\operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} A \subseteq \operatorname{int}  \operatorname{cl} A$$

giving us the other inclusion.

I think the above reads somewhat smoother, but it comes down to the same type of argument based on trivial facts combined with monotonicity.

Comment: Thank you, this was what i was looking for. i.e. a “smoother” proof. Thanks!